# Unable to add a new ppt slide from Excel VBA, Error 429

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am working on a topic wherein I need to export Excel data into PowerPoint. Everything was working great till I had only one slide. But When I tried to add another slide, it shows error:

> run time error 429 : Active x component cannot create an Object.

Here is my code:

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide 
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout 
'my code
Set pptLayout = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).CustomLayout 'error at this line
Set pptSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.AddSlide(2, pptLayout)
```

Don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your code works if run from within PowerPoint itself. Are you using late or early binding? Ie, have you set a reference to PowerPoint?  As a test, try dimming the variables as Object.

Comment: yes I have reference to a PowerPoint. What do you mean by code running from within PowerPoint ? @SteveRindsberg

Comment: I just meant that I ran your code within PowerPoint to verify that it worked as expected. When you're automating PPT from another program, sometimes it's simpler and faster to debug the PPT part IN Powerpoint.

Answer (score 0):

That code works ok for me when there is one slide in the deck but of course it does fail when there are no slides in the deck because it's referencing slide 1 to get a reference to its custom layout.

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptLayout As CustomLayout
'my code
With ActivePresentation
  ' If the deck has some slides, get a freference to the first slide's custom layout
  If .Slides.Count > 0 Then
    Set pptLayout = .Slides(1).CustomLayout 'error at this line
  Else
    ' If no slides in the deck, use the second custom layout from the master
    ' (usually the Title and Content layout
    Set pptLayout = .SlideMaster.Design.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(2)
  End If
  Set pptSlide = .Slides.AddSlide(.Slides.Count + 1, pptLayout)
End With
```

Comment: Hi, tried to integreate your code to mine . Still gives the same error. at the line `With Active Presentation`

Comment: Perhaps you should include more of your code than just the snippets you've provided so far.

Comment: It works when I add oPPTApp.ActivePresentation. But the new slide added does not have the same layout as the previous. It is a blank slide with a Title. How can I get exactly the same Format as the previous slide.

Comment: `Set pptSlide = oPPTApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate` works fine for me but gives a type mismatch error. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Hej, 
I had the same error. 
When you duplicate a slide it becomes a SlideRange. All you need to do is to take the first item from the range as below:

```
    Dim spptRange As SlideRange
    Dim sppt As PowerPoint.Slide
    Set spptRange = PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(spptNr).Duplicate
    Set sppt = spptRange.Item(1)
```